# Update available page layouts of web using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, client-object-model

Is it possible to update the available page layouts of a web using CSOM? In the interface you can change them by going to the site setting and then to page layout and site template settings, but I didn't find an option yet to do it in code.

**EDIT**

It looks like I'm able to change the pagelayouts by changing the "__PageLayouts" property of the web. The current value looks like this (I manually did the formatting to make it a bit more readable):

```
<pagelayouts>
  <layout guid="a62d560d-d34d-4154-80b5-7163e91cd62e" url="_catalogs/masterpage/ContactPage.aspx" />
  <layout guid="efc0944d-4992-4c14-a0d4-5c1632bb04b5" url="_catalogs/masterpage/HowDoI.aspx" />
</pagelayouts>
```

The thing is, I don't got a clue where these guids are coming from and if I'm able to retrieve them using CSOM

Comment: Each unique page and list should have it's own unique GUID.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to retrieve that unique GUID?

Answer (score 2):

Having reflected the assembly that provides the SetAvailablePageLayouts, I can confirm that all it is doing is setting the "__PageLayouts" web property (and pushing this update to child webs). As such using CSOM to set the property should be sufficient. I assume that the GUID is the UniqueId of the page layout in _catalogs/masterpage gallery.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft'S API, there is a function called [SetAvailablePageLayouts()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb.setavailablepagelayouts%28v=office.12%29.aspx) that let'S you, like it says, set the available page layouts for a PublishingPage object.  In C#, the general function definition is

```
public void SetAvailablePageLayouts(
PageLayout[] pageLayouts,
bool resetAllSubsitesToInherit
)
```

Just create a new publishing page object by using GetPublishingWeb($your_SPWeb_var), and then call this function, setting the pageLayouts array with the list of layouts you want to allow.

**EDIT:** Note that this is for the server-side API, which you may not want to use.  I will search for a similar use for client-side, and update my answer accordingly.  For now, wait for more appropriate answers.

Comment: Is this method really available in the client side API? Your link is refering to the server side API

Comment: Ahh, misunderstood the question, you are absolutely right.  I will append the question to reflect this, and continue searching the client-side API.  Thank you!